# Composer could not find typo3cms when running `fixfolderstructure` in TYPO3

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-11.x

When running `composer install` or `composer update` during the upgrade process from TYPO3 v10 to v11 I face the following error messages:

> sh: 1: typo3cms: not found

or

> Der Befehl "typo3cms" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.

followed by

> Script typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure handling the typo3-cms-scripts event returned with error code 1
> Script @typo3-cms-scripts was called via post-autoload-dump

In my `commposer.json` I have those lines, triggering the scripts:

```
    "scripts":{
        "typo3-cms-scripts": [
            "typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@typo3-cms-scripts"
        ]
    },
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the TYPO3 Console the error disappeared.

`composer require helhum/typo3-console:*`

Comment: if you could also share (in case you know) why that dependency was needed, I'm sure future users will thank you for that (and it would make the answer a three-liner with code in the middle, so makes it a beauty). And don't forget to accept it to mark the question answered (or comment if you're waiting for community feedback still)

Comment: @hakre Sorry, I could not find out why, I only found a way to solve my problem.
The `*` for the version was needed. Otherwise I got version conflicts while installing the package.

Comment: Is the fixfolderstructure still needed in TYPO3 v11 when using repositories of `"type": "path"` for custom extensions / themes or could I remove it as an alternative solution (did not check that)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that because limited typo3 knowledge. If I were you I'd certainly give it a try especially after you've been already able to find one solution and from my understanding without fixfolderstructure is probably better.

Comment: Never need to fix the folder structure after a simple composer update and we do a lot of them. Only needed by migration or core version upgrade (10 to 11).

Comment: I didn't mention it but it was a core update from v10 to v11. I added this information to the question. Thank's for sharing your knowledge @HeinzSchilling